# SonarQube: Message displayed in PHP code

Tags: php, sonarqube, psr-2

I have this statement:

```
return ++$maxContratNum;
```

SonarQube display this message:

> Extract this increment or decrement operator into a dedicated
>   statement

what's meaning this message ??

Thank you

Comment: try to increment the number before returning it rather than returning as incrementing. example: `$return_value = ++$maxContratNum;return $return_value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is trying to tell you to write like this:

```
++$maxContratNum;
return $maxContratNum;
```

Written this way, it's perfectly clear that the value of `$maxContratNum` is incremented, and the function returns that incremented value.

If you write `return ++$maxContratNum;`, that may be confusing to some readers.